# Local Symmetry or gauge transformation of second kind in QED

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

While ensuring the gauge invariance of the lagrangian $$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}+\bar{\psi}(i \not \partial-m) \psi-e \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} A_{\mu} \psi$$ we consider the gauge transformations of the form $$A_{\mu} \rightarrow A_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu} \lambda \quad \text { and } \quad \psi \rightarrow e^{-i e \lambda} \psi$$ with arbritrary $\lambda$(x).
$\textbf{How $ \psi \rightarrow e^{-i e \lambda} \psi$ represents a gauge transformation of a spinor field?}$ In weinberg book the author metioned that  infinitesimal internal symmetries of the action imply the existence of conserved currents. In particular, if the transformation $$\delta \Psi^{l}(x)=i \epsilon(x) q \Psi^{l}(x)$$leaves the matter action invariant for a constant $\epsilon,$ then for general infinitesimal functions $\epsilon(x)$ the change in the matter action must take the form $$
\delta I_{M}=-\int d^{4} x J^{\mu}(x) \partial^{\mu} \epsilon(x)
$$
When the matter fields satisfy their field equations, the matter action is stationary with respect to any variation of the $\Psi_{\ell},$ so in this case must vanish, and hence
$$\partial_{\mu} J^{\mu}=0$$
Then the author shows how the gauge transformations of the form mentioned above ensures the invariance of the lagrangian even though it includes covariant fied derivative $\partial_{\mu} \Psi^{l}(x)$. Can we say that the transformation $ \psi \rightarrow e^{-i e \lambda} \psi$ is ensuring the invariance of the lagrangian even when it consists derivative and this is possible because $\lambda$ is same for both transformation. Hence $ \psi \rightarrow e^{-i e \lambda} \psi$ also represents gauge transformation?

Comment: Which page in Weinberg?

Comment: @Qmechanic page 341,342,343 volume I